# tool to visualize C sourcecode

Tags: c, visualization

It's always hard to understand new code,
especially if it is spread over many files with
hundreds of functions - like most linux kernel parts.

I think it is easier to understand the big picture if it is
visualized and if you can follow the links "with your eyes".

I am therefore looking for a tool to visualize C code,
which function is calling which one, where is the entry
and so on.

I would prefer a vscode plugin but it doesn't really matter.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try these tools:

https://github.com/johnyf/pycflow2dot
Layout C call graphs from cflow using GraphViz dot

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joaompinto.vscode-graphviz
vscode extension for Graphviz

http://www.gson.org/egypt
egypt - a tool for making call graphs

https://kcachegrind.github.io
KCachegrind profiling tool Callgrind and the profile data visualization